# PyAutoGUI Code works fine within Visual Studio Code but else I get No Such File Error

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have this line in my Code with a picture in the same file location

```
buttonlocation = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('button.png')
```

This code works fine within Visual Studio Code, but whenever I try to run the .py file itself I get this error
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'button.png'`

Do i have to specify the full path or am I missing something?

Comment: did you try "./button.png"

Comment: not yet, gonna try that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem.

Most probably, you have `'button.png'` is in a folder which is set as working directory inside VS Code. Hence, the code runs and you get the correct output.

In other cases, you have not set the same folder as your working directory and it makes a difference.

The trick is to keep the file `'button.png'` in the right folder.